# How to set Dynamic width and height for an inflated view(button)

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I've an activity and I can to create some button programmatically on it with LayoutInflater, like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
Button newButton = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_button, currentTableRow, false);
```

and my_button.xml:

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/newButton"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"</Button>
```

it works fine. But my question is that: Is there any way that I pass the width and height to my_button.xml or any way that when I want to inflate that view, set the width and height. I mean that sometime I want to set "30dp", sometimes set it to "45dp" etc.Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you looking for newButton.setHeight(int); newButton.setWidth(int) ?

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez yes, or some way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

button.getLayoutParams().height = 30 * scale;
button.getLayoutParams().width = 30 * scale;
```

by using above code one can simply set height and width in "dp".

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
newButton .setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams(45, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

where `LayoutParams(int width, int height)`

means first argument is width and second argument is height ..

Answer (score 0):

In **Kotlin** you can do like this:

```
val scale=this.resources.displayMetrics.density
btn.layoutParams.width=(40 * scale).toInt()
btn.layoutParams.height=(40 * scale).toInt()
```

where height and width must be integer number